# Proper Component Tree for Array within Array Rerender on Change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

Im wracking my brain trying to understand the component structure here that I should employ. I feel like this is something that I absolutely want to get correctly because going forward it's important to understand how a ReactJS application should look and how to correctly separate the concerns. I know it is an opinionated front but how I am currently doing it is not correct, and I was looking for some insight.

Data Model: This is a large array of Recipes, each contains another array of ingredients. I want to allow the user to "tick off" (the ingredient is removed from the array) the ingredients as they buy them/acquire them.

```
[
    ...
    {
        "title": "Recipe 1"
        "ingredients": [
            { "title": "Flour", "measurement": "300g" },
            { "title": "Sesame Seeds", "measurement": "1 Tblsp" }
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

Current Psuedo Component Tree:

```
// RecipeList is my "HOC" (higher-order component) and contains all the functions/data required for the rest of the tree, and simply passes them down as props. This is `connect()`ed to the store here.
<RecipeList>
    // Map on the highest level array to display a <Recipe> component for each
    <Recipe data={recipe[mappedIndex]}>
        // Map on each ingredient to create a list item for each
        <RecipeIngredient data={recipe[mappedIndex].ingredient[mappedIndex]>
            <IngredientCheckBox onChange={ //remove this ingredient from the array } />
        </RecipeIngredient>
    </Recipe>
</RecipeList>
```

All is well with the above, the data is displayed exactly how I would expect it to.

However, and this is the **main issue**, when it comes to `onChange` I call an action, `COMPLETE_INGREDIENT` which basically removes it from the `ingredients` array (I see it in action, using `redux-logger` the `next-state` does not contain it).

Unfortunately, my components don't rerender. It is no longer in the array but is still displayed on screen. I understand this may one of the following reasons:

- `connect()` only shallow compares the states so doesn't trigger a rerender because it is a value in an array, inside of a property of an object in an array.
- My `connect()` is too far from the action, and should be re`connect()`ed at a deeper component level, say the `<Recipe>` component and only attach it to a part of the store that it cares about (could even be the `<RecipeIngredient>`).
- My reducer is not modifying the state in an immutable way. This is the one I have spent most time on, however even using `slice()` and the sorts, I still can't get it to re-render

Edit: My reducer for action `COMPLETE_INGREDIENT`. I understand this may be the issue, as it is directly mutating the state. What would be the correct way for such a deep change to the state?

```
case COMPLETE_INGREDIENT:
    // state is from a level above the recipe's, that contains a timestamp etc
    state.recipes[action.payload.recipeIndex].ingredients.splice(action.payload.ingredientIndex, 1)

    return Object.assign({
        ...state
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Edit: My reducer for action COMPLETE_INGREDIENT. I understand this may
>   be the issue, as it is directly mutating the state. What would be the
>   correct way for such a deep change to the state?

Yep, you are mutating state with that Object.assign. As a first argument it should have new Object to copy values to and return:

```
return Object.assign({}, {
    ...state
})
```

Based on your code I've created updating function I would probably create:

```
case COMPLETE_INGREDIENT: {
  const { recipeIndex, ingregientIndex } = action.payload;
  const recipesListCopy = [...state.recipes];
  const recipeCopy = {
    ...recipesListCopy[recipeIndex],
    ingredients: recipesListCopy[recipeIndex].ingredients.filter(
      (e, index) => index !== ingredientIndex
    )
  };
  recipesListCopy[recipeIndex] = recipeCopy;
  return {
    ...state,
    recipes: recipesListCopy
  };
}
```

Edit:

based on your comment - *"remove the recipe from the top level recipe array if the ingredients array is now empty"*

```
case COMPLETE_INGREDIENT: {
  const { recipeIndex, ingregientIndex } = action.payload;
  const recipesListCopy = [...state.recipes];
  const updatedIngredientsList = recipesListCopy[recipeIndex].ingredients.filter(
    (e, index) => index !== ingredientIndex
  );

  if(updatedIngredientsList.length > 0) { 
    // update ingredients
    const recipeCopy = {
      ...recipesListCopy[recipeIndex],
      ingredients: updatedIngredientsList
    };
    recipesListCopy[recipeIndex] = recipeCopy;
  } else { 
    // remove recipe because no igridients
    recipesListCopy.splice(recipeIndex, 1);
  }

  return {
    ...state,
    recipes: recipesListCopy
  };
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, how would I modify this to also remove the recipe from the top level `recipe` array if the `ingredients` array is now empty?

Comment: @Aleski Not sure what you mean by "removing top level recipe"

Comment: Ok, so what I meant was that if the ingredients are now empty, because it has been removed (basically it was the last ingredient) I need to have the recipe ALSO removed from the top level array (`recipe: []`)

Comment: Is splice ok to use here?

Comment: @Aleski tez its okay because it is copied array

Comment: Ah ok, I am beginning to see the immutable/mutable pattern now

Comment: In the above, is `ingredients: ingredientsCopy` meant to be equal to the cut down copy of the original array `updatedIngredientList` ?

Comment: @Aleski my mistake it's supposed to be `ingredients: updatedIngredientsList`. I've corrected the answer.

Comment: Thanks, as I can see now modifying state in such a way can get pretty crazy. Any suggestions on breaking down the amount of `map` and `filter` I must do when modifying data like this?

Comment: @Aleski I'm not sure. Take a look at [normalizr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/normalizr)

Answer (score 1):

Problem here is in mutating existing state

```
case COMPLETE_INGREDIENT:
// state is from a level above the recipe's, that contains a timestamp etc
state.recipes[action.payload.recipeIndex].ingredients.splice(action.payload.ingredientIndex, 1)

return Object.assign({
    ...state
})
```

Method `splice` changes existing array, but you need to create new array. Here is example

```
const obj = { a: { b: 5 } };
const copyObj = { ...obj };
copyObj.a.b = 1;
console.log(obj.a.b); // 1
console.log(copyObj.a.b); // 1
```

You have copied `state` object but `ingredients` array stays the same. So you need to copy array.

```
case COMPLETE_INGREDIENT:
return {
  ...state,
  recipes: state.recipes.map(
    (item, index) =>
      index === action.payload.recipeIndex
        ? { ...item, ingredients: item.ingredients.filter((item, index) => index !== action.payload.ingredientIndex) }
        : item
  ),
};
```